# How to properly Create a Button in SwiftUI. The code works but it is throwing an error in the next line of code it was rewrote it

Tags: xcode, button, swiftui

/*
The following code produces two warinings:
No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression
'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block
*/

```
     Button("Delete Account", role: .destructive) {
                    
                            do {
                                try Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete()  
                                userIsLoggedIn = false
                                email = ""
                                password = ""
                            } catch {  
                                // handle error
                            }
                       }
                    }
                } else {
                    content
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                        .navigationTitle("ChatMate")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                
            }
        }
    }
```

//I rewrite the code and it produce the following:

```
                        Button("Delete Account", role: .destructive) {
                        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
                            user.delete { error in
                                if let error = error {
                                    // handle error
                                } else {
                                    userIsLoggedIn = false
                                    email = ""
                                    password = ""
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

/*But there is a bracket or something missing because this thows an error in the next line of code:
Cannot declare local computed variable in result builder
*/

```
var content: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Circle()
                .scale(1.7)
                .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.15))
            Circle()
                .scale(1.35)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
```

```
        VStack {
            Text("Login")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
            TextField("email", text: $email)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                .background(Color.black.opacity(0.25))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .textCase(.lowercase)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                .background(Color.black.opacity(0.25))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is going on you don’t need ChatGPT

Comment: Notice that chatgtp generated content isn’t allowed here on stackoverflow so you should remove that part from your question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to delete one bracket and change the

if let error = error {

to

user.delete { error in
if error != nil {